# Diacritics inside an Epigraph in LyX

Tags: lyx, input-encodings

I can use letters marked with diacritics in most parts of my document.
Now, I'm making an epigraph

```
\epigraph{,evlos t'nac uoy melborp a si ereht fI''\\
''.ti dnif :evlos nac uoy melborp reisae na si ereht neht}{aylóP egroeG}
```

(the quote is written in reverse because I'm using LyX in Hebrew and that's the way to make it write left-to-right in an ERT).

Anyway, it doesn't compile. It does compile if I remove the 'ó'.

The error is:

> Could not find LaTeX command for character 'ó' (code point 0xf3).

And its description is:

> Some characters of your document are probably not representable in the chosen encoding.
>   Changing the document encoding to utf8 could help.

Changing to utf8 *does* help if I don't use Hebrew in my document. The way I did it is through Document->Settings->Language->Encoding->Unicode (utf8).

But, if I do write anything in Hebrew in the document, then changing to utf8 causes the following error (per Hebrew character):

> Package inputenc Error: Unicode Character '\u8' not set up for use in LaTeX.

Comment: Use `\'o` instead of the accented character.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer; I usually don't look at LyX tagged questions. We had the "Answer the unanswered" session yesterday and it caught my eye.

Comment: The final exam in the course where this document was used has just ended a few minutes ago, so it was just in time for the students to see the correct spelling :) Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what's going wrong, as there's no real example. However, using the "command" syntax `\'{o}` instead of the UTF-8 character `ó` might solve the issue.

The result should be the same, because LaTeX just converts `ó` to `\'{o}` before proceeding on.